# Graphing a large number of plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid

I'm fitting a dose-response curve to many data sets that I want to plot to a single file.

Here's how one data set looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(dose=c(10,0.625,2.5,0.156,0.0391,0.00244,0.00977,0.00061,10,0.625,2.5,0.156,0.0391,0.00244,0.00977,0.00061,10,0.625,2.5,0.156,0.0391,0.00244,0.00977,0.00061),viability=c(6.12,105,57.9,81.9,86.5,98.3,96.4,81.8,27.3,85.2,80.8,92,82.5,110,90.2,76.6,11.9,89,35.4,79,95.8,117,82.1,95.1),stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Here's the dose-response fit:

```
library(drc)
fit <- drm(viability~dose,data=df,fct=LL.4(names=c("Slope","Lower Limit","Upper Limit","ED50")))
```

Now I'm predicting values in order to plot the curve:

```
pred.df <- expand.grid(dose=exp(seq(log(max(df$dose)),log(min(df$dose)),length=100))) 
pred <- predict(fit,newdata=pred.df,interval="confidence") 
pred.df$viability <- pred[,1]
pred.df$viability.low <- pred[,2]
pred.df$viability.high <- pred[,3]
```

And this is how a single plot looks like:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df,aes(x=dose,y=viability))+geom_point()+geom_ribbon(data=pred.df,aes(x=dose,y=viability,ymin=viability.low,ymax=viability.high),alpha=0.2)+labs(y="viability")+
  geom_line(data=pred.df,aes(x=dose,y=viability))+coord_trans(x="log")+theme_bw()+scale_x_continuous(name="dose",breaks=sort(unique(df$dose)),labels=format(signif(sort(unique(df$dose)),3),scientific=T))+ggtitle(label="all doses")
```

adding a few parameter estimates to the plot:

```
params <- signif(summary(fit)$coefficient[-1,1],3)
names(params) <- c("lower","upper","ed50")
p <- p + annotate("text",size=3,hjust=0,x=2.4e-3,y=5,label=paste(sapply(1:length(params),function(p) paste0(names(params)[p],"=",params[p])),collapse="\n"),colour="black")
```

Which gives:

[image]

Now suppose I have 20 of these that I want to cram in a single figure file.

I thought that a reasonable solution would be to use `grid.arrange`:

As an example I'll loop 20 times on this example data set:

```
plot.list <- vector(mode="list",20)
for(i in 1:20){
  plot.list[[i]] <- ggplot(df,aes(x=dose,y=viability))+geom_point()+geom_ribbon(data=pred.df,aes(x=dose,y=viability,ymin=viability.low,ymax=viability.high),alpha=0.2)+labs(y="viability")+
    geom_line(data=pred.df,aes(x=dose,y=viability))+coord_trans(x="log")+theme_bw()+scale_x_continuous(name="dose",breaks=sort(unique(df$dose)),labels=format(signif(sort(unique(df$dose)),3),scientific=T))+ggtitle(label="all doses")+
    annotate("text",size=3,hjust=0,x=2.4e-3,y=5,label=paste(sapply(1:length(params),function(p) paste0(names(params)[p],"=",params[p])),collapse="\n"),colour="black")
}
```

And then plot using:

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(grobs=plot.list,ncol=3,nrow=ceiling(length(plot.list)/3))
```

[image]

Which is obviously poorly scaled. So my question is how to create this figure with better scaling - meaning that all objects are compressed proportionally in way that produces a figure that is still visually interperable.

Comment: Plot to a file and use large values for `height` and `width`. And maybe cut back on the redundant labels. Or combine all your predictions into one data frame and use `facet_wrap`.

Comment: `png("myplot.png", width = 1600, height = 2400); grid.arrange(...); dev.off()`

Comment: BTW you don't need to specify both nrow and ncol in grid.arrange()

Answer (score 2):

You should set the device size so that the plots remain readable, e.g.

```
pl = replicate(11, qplot(1,1), simplify = FALSE)
g = arrangeGrob(grobs = pl, ncol=3)
ggsave("plots.pdf", g, width=15, height=20)
```

[image]